# Ratchet with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ratchet

I am trying to integrate Ratchet with Laravel.

I have added the following in the handle() of Command class

```
public function handle()
{


    $this->info('Server running');
    $loop = Factory::create();
    $webSock = new Server($loop);
    $webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');

    $webServer = new IoServer(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new WampServer(
                    new EventHandler($loop) // This is my class. Pass in the loop!
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
    }
```

This command is working properly when executed from CLI

Now what will be the effect if I add the following code in the Controller:

```
Bus::dispatch(
    new RatchetCommand()
);
```

Will multiple instances of the server start ? Because that Controller will be called multiple times.

Comment: make a route and call ratchet command in it. You can do this by using Artisan facade. Like Artisan::call("commandName");

Comment: I can call it, but the question is whether MULTIPLE INSTANCES of server will start ?